# Hibernate query to select rows within a time range of a Datetime column

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a table `DeviceData` with columns `Username, Watts, and CreatedOn`, where `CreatedOn` is of type `Datetime (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)`. All three columns form a composite key and are an `@Embeddable` class in Hibernate.

```
@Embeddable
public class TimeSeriesPowerPK implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String username;
    private Integer watts;
    private String dateTime;

    public TimeSeriesPowerPK(String username, Integer watts, String dateTime) {
        this.username = username;
        this.watts = watts;
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public Integer getWatts() {
        return watts;
    }

    public void setWatts(Integer watts) {
        this.watts = watts;
    }

    public String getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

}
```

How should I write my query in the DAO shown below to retrieve all Watts values of rows whose createdOn is between the current time and a user entered number of hours or minutes?

```
public List<Integer> getPowerUsageForUser(String minutes) {
    List<Integer> powerUsedList = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("***query***").list();
    return powerUsedList;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Updated question to retrieve a particular column's value of all selected rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following code

```
public List<TimeSeriesPowerPK> getPowerUsageForUser(String minutes) {
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("From TimeSeriesPowerPK where dateTime <=:param1 AND dateTime >= :parma2 ");
query.setParameter("param1",currentDateObject);
query.setParameter("param2",userEnteredDateObject);
List<TimeSeriesPowerPK> powerUsedList=query.list();
return powerUsedList;
```

}

Note that dateTime of the class must be mapped to createdOn column of database table.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Criteria

```
public List<TimeSeriesPowerPK> getPowerUsageForUser() {

        Criteria powerCriteria= session.createCriteria(TimeSeriesPowerPK.class);
        powerCriteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

        powerCriteria.add(Restrictions.le("dateTime",currentDateObject));
        powerCriteria.add(Restrictions.ge("dateTime",userEnteredDateObject));

        return powerCriteria.list();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Query qrFetch=ursession.createQuery("from TimeSeriesPowerPK where dateTime between :start_date and :end_date");
qrFetch.setParameter("start_date",currentDateObject);
qrFetch.setParameter("end_date",userEnteredDateObject);
List<TimeSeriesPowerPK> timeSeriesPowerPKList=qrFetch.list();
```